# codemirror for just one-line-textfield?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I have a one line textfield. (input type='text')

I don't have a textarea.

This textfield allows the user to enter small strings in a simple DSL.
To give you an idea they look like this:

- from milan to london
- from italy(rome,florence) to uk

I was thinking to replace this textfield with codemirror

my questions are:

- is using code mirror for one line textarea a good idea ?
- has anybody done this ?
- are there any other approaches to make a textfield more 'colourful' ?

Thanks,

Comment: Isn't CodeMirror an in-browser code editing tool? I don't see how your input field requires a code-editor ? What do you mean by 'colourful'?

Comment: @nimod: Syntax highlighting I presume.

Comment: You could use a textarea and set its height to one row. It seems to be an "ok" approach to me. It's certainly not bad and building something on your own is probably more difficult. You still have to create the language parser though, so that the right tokens are correctly highlighted.

Comment: Unless you're already using the editor on the page for something worth using it, I can't see why you wouldn't write a little script instead of having a fully blown code-editor ... @FelixKling how is that not bad?

Comment: @nimod sorry yes 'colourful' meant syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Felix Kling yes I still have to create my language parser (but even borrowing the javascript theme will do the trick) thanks for your help

Comment: @nimrod: I would not call codemirror a "fully blown code-editor". All it does is actually syntax highlighting (in its core). Sure, if the language is not large, a custom solution might not be that difficult, but I believe making it work properly in all (most) possible circumstances (which includes proper styling) will require ore than a little script. One can always build a custom solution later on when running into performance issues.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, there is a way to make a single-line editor using rich capabilities of CodeMirror.
First, you'll have to add a full-featured CodeMirror object (use a textarea).

Assume you've got `var cm = CodeMirror(...)`. (Use `value: ""`).
Then do

```
cm.setSize(200, cm.defaultTextHeight() + 2 * 4);
// 200 is the preferable width of text field in pixels,
// 4 is default CM padding (which depends on the theme you're using)

// now disallow adding newlines in the following simple way
cm.on("beforeChange", function(instance, change) {
    var newtext = change.text.join("").replace(/\n/g, ""); // remove ALL \n !
    change.update(change.from, change.to, [newtext]);
    return true;
});

// and then hide ugly horizontal scrollbar
cm.on("change", function(instance, change) {
    $(".CodeMirror-hscrollbar").css('display', 'none');
    // (!) this code is using jQuery and the selector is quite imperfect if
    // you're using more than one CodeMirror on your page. you're free to
    // change it appealing to your page structure.
});

// the following line fixes a bug I've encountered in CodeMirror 3.1
$(".CodeMirror-scroll").css('overflow', 'hidden');
// jQuery again! be careful with selector or move this to .css file
```

This works just fine for me.

Comment: nice beforeChange hack, thahks

Comment: Not all changes have an update function (i.e undo) so you need to check it exists first:
    if (change.update) change.update(change.from, change.to, [newtext]);

Also, you might want to disable some key mappings by adding the following config:
    extraKeys: { "Tab": false, "Shift-Tab": false, "Enter": false }

Comment: Thanks man, this is one of the best answers ever. Everything I wanted to know was in your post. Totally fixed me up :) Prob saved me 2 days faffing around with it. Much appreciated. God bless you :D Still working 4 years later!

Comment: @danday74 Well, if it's still working, we have to thank CodeMirror developers for stability :)

Answer (score 2):

You could just run a regex on the field when somebody hits a key.

When the event happens you do a str.replace on the content of a contentEditable element which is about one line high kinda like this:

```
var r = /from\s+(\w+)\s+to\s+(\w+)/gi
s.replace(r, 'from <em>$1</em> to <em class="to">$2</em>');
```

for that kind of approach you wouldn't need a code-editor, and you could just style your tags with these classes...

simples

Comment: really like this suggestion... unless somebody comes with something better I will tag this as the 'correct' answer